# React-Select as optional auto complete field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Is there a way to use [React-Select](https://react-select.com/home) as an optional auto complete field? I mean something like this..

1. If user selects a value from the dropdown options, the value is the option value (or label)
2. If user doesn't select an option and has typed something in the input field, that text is the value.
3. If user neither selects an option nor types anything, the value is empty.

Comment: case 1 and 3 will automatically work in react select and for 2nd case.
check 'creatable' option in react select -  https://react-select.com/home#creatable or https://react-select.com/creatable